# Prevent dart URI from modifying query

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm having an issue with Dart URI when I enter spaces in a query. I'm fetching data from pokemontcg.io API (v2).

I even tried creating a new URI with queryParameters prop thinking that it would not modify my query (...).

The issue is that URI is replacing empty spaces with "+", but the API is not allowing these types of values, it requires an empty space in the query..

So I could I do this in dart ?

Examples:

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse(
  "https://api.pokemontcg.io/v2/cards?q=supertype:pokemon ${query.length > 0 ? query : ''}&pageSize=10");
```

This uri with Http.get will work for pokemons queries without a space in the name like "pikatchu" but not with "dark pikatchu" because "dark pikatichu" will be transformed to "dark+pikatch"

Thanks

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem.  With your example query, spaces are being correctly replaced by `%20`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so, I'm just dumb xD. The api mentions that you need to put double quotes when you enter a name with spaces like "dark ampharos"

```
 'name:' + (query.contains(' ') ? '"$query"' : query)
```

I just added this in my query :) Hope this will help even though it's a simple issue to solve.